# Loading images from xcassets into NSImage

Tags: objective-c, macos

In Xcode 12.4 on macOS Big Sur, I'm developing an Objective-C plug-in of a third-party app running on macOS 10.12 and newer. I would like to load an image from an asset catalog.

I've added `abc.xcassets` into the project tree, added several PDF images. One of the image is named `test`.

I would like to show the `test` image as an alert icon. For this purpose, I'm trying to load the image into an `NSImage` instance in the main plug-in's class. I've tried all the alternatives I found but I still get `nil` instead of the image.

```
+ (void)initialize {
    NSImage *test1 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"test"];
    NSImage *test2 = [NSImage imageNamed:@"test" bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSBundle *testBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSImage *test3 = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                        [testBundle pathForImageResource:@"test"]];

    // Later used in
    // [alert setIcon:test1];
}
```

However, all the `test1`, `test2` and `test3` are `nil` after running this code. What am I missing? How to do it properly?

PS: The `test` image is listed by Xcode's UI builder to select in buttons' `Image` property.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
[testBundle imageForResource:@"test"]
```